# Store user chosen start activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sharedpreferences, store

my app has two activities and the user can chose which one he want to have as start-activity. How do I store his choice? I guess SharedPreferences, but how does this work?

Thank you!

Comment: `how does this work?` It **doesn't**. The launcher Activity is stored in the Manifest. BUT! You can use a fake "Splash-Screen" to launch this or that Activity, based on a string you can store in the Preferences. THIS is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Just create third activity that will be really start activity (set it as main activity in manifest). In onCreate read SharedPreferences and launch the activity you need.